# I can't parse the data from a JSON encoded string

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse some option data from a JSON encoded string. This is the code I already have:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode('{"1":"{\"QID\":\"1\",\"Type\":\"MC\",\"Question\":\"Question here\",\"Options\":{\"1\":\"Answer Opt 1\"}}"}');
foreach ($json as $QID => $Data) {
echo "QID: $QID, Type: ";
$new = json_decode(stripslashes($Data));
if($new->Type=="MC"){
    echo "Multiple Choice, Question: ".$new->Question.", Options: ";
    $options = json_decode($new->Options,true);
}else{
    echo "Unknown";
}
echo ".<br/>";
}
?>
```

The JSON string provided is what is sent to the script, The error I get is :

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

The VarDump of $new->Options is:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["1"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Comment: So it's already a parsed object. Why would you like to parse it once again?

Comment: PS: `stripslashes($Data)` --- this doesn't look right

Comment: @zerkms I have realised my error and figured it out now, I am still getting used to PHP! About the stripslashes, is it not required?

Comment: generally - not. If it's required - it means someone added extra-slashes. Like magic quotes, or you :-)

Comment: @zerkms Well this is part of a public control panel, so probably safe to keep it in :)

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery?

Comment: @ColeJohnson The JSON data is sent to this PHP script via JQuery

Comment: @FelixKing there's bound to be a PHP plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is malformed.
After I do the `stripslashes` the JSON should be formed like the following to be valid:

```
{
    "1": {
        "QID": "1",
        "Type": "MC",
        "Question": "Questionhere",
        "Options": {
            "1": "AnswerOpt1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. after the stripslashes it ends up being malformed. Also though technically your original json might be in a valid form, I don't believe its useful and can be converted into an array unless its in the above format